# SQL Server AND AND OR AND AND

Tags: sql, sql-server

Stupid question but is there a difference between

```
Select * from TableA
where 
System=1 and Acct=2 and FiscalNo=4
or
System=2 and FiscalNo=4 and SubAcct=1521
```

AND

```
Select * from TableA
where 
(System=1 and Acct=2 and FiscalNo=4)
or
(System=2 and FiscalNo=4 and SubAcct=1521)
```

notice the difference is brackets
the first query does not have brackets

Comment: Other than easiness to read, there's no other difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It shouldn't matter much](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx) because of the order of operations within the SQL statement.  It will still prioritize AND over OR.

Answer (score 3):

`AND` binds with higher priority than `OR`. Therefore, there is no difference.

Use style 2 for clarity, though. That obviates the need for this question.